# jQuery typing functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

This was merely a syntax error from long ago. See answer!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Well obviously it doesn't work, you wouldn't be asking if it did. What *exactly* doesn't work? What does it do now? Does it not type the question? Does it not ask for an answer? Are there errors in the error console?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm getting console errors out the ass here: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function line 7 $(function(){
        $(".element").editableDiv();
      )};

Comment: @RyanCasalino, BTW, why are you using so many jquery `on document ready` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your setTimeout syntax is a bit off:

```
window.onload = $(function() {
  $(".element").typed({
    strings: ['Are you down with the movement(Y/N)?'],
    typeSpeed: 150
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".element").editableDiv();
  }, 1000)
});
```

What's the editable jQuery plugin you're using?

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/jQuery-Plugin-For-Editable-DIV-Elements-editableDiv.html

Comment: If you're only using the editable div jQuery plugin to set a jQuery element to contenteditable, you can do that without bringing a plugin into it: 


$(".element").attr('contenteditable', true);